# Is there an optical element that can perform inverse Fourier transform?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, fourier-transform

We know that lenses perform Fourier transform of the incident wave-field distribution. Is there a similar optical element that can perform inverse Fourier transform such that when the output of a lens is combined with this element, we recover the original wave-field distribution

Comment: The same element with the light going in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 5):

The inverse Fourier transform differs from the Fourier transform only by a flip operator, so for many purposes they can be treated as the same thing. Hence you can apply an inverse transform simply by using a second identical lens.

Comment: Just to avoid any misinterpretation: this only holds so long as you don't have an imaging plane, because in that case you lose the phase info (e.g.  diffuse reflector).

Comment: So you are suggesting that if I put two lens side by side and illuminate an object from one side of the lens, I will get the image of the object from the other side?

Comment: The lenses have to be in series so the input is Fourier transformed as the light passes through the first lens then transformed again as it passes through the second lens. I'd have to think about the geometry. As I recall the FT is at the focal plane, so possibly place the lenses a distance apart equal to the sum of the focal lengths.